# Regex - Getting letters preceded and followed by a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get all letters, including letters before and after underline "_". But I also don't want to get words like "pi", "\Delta" and "\Sigma".

How to do this in Regex JS?

```
/\b([^e|_|\d|\W])\b/gim /*my regex*/

(1)/(2)+p_a*r*e*t*a*v+pi+\delta+\sigma

(1)/(2)+a_t*e*j*h*o+ \Delta

(1)/(2)+p_w
```

Comment: show the full list of non capturing words and text

Comment: @Kaushik here has a regex (https://regex101.com/r/LWQ9PG/1/) with the lyrics I already got. I need to get all the letters before and after "_" except the letter "e". I don't want to take words or not-words either. This is an equation and I need to capture all the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all the letters a-z except the e, you could use a capturing group and a (negated) character class:

```
[_\W]([a-df-z])(?![^_\W])
```

- `[_\W]` Match an `_` or match a non word char
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-df-z]` Match a lowercase a-z except e
- `)` Close group
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `[^_\W]` Match any char except `_` or a non word char
- `)` Close lookahead

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jgGvRZ/1)

```js
const regex = /[_\W]([a-df-z])(?![^_\W])/g;
let str = `(1)/(2)+p_a*r*e*t*a*v+pi+\\delta+\\sigma

(1)/(2)+a_t*e*j*h*o+ \\Delta

(1)/(2)+p_w

`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: is there any way not to get the following signs: +, *, _, (, ) ? Only the letters?

Comment: @PedroCastro One option is to use a positive lookbehind but that is not widely supported but it is by Chome for example `(?<=[_\W])[a-df-z](?![^_\W])` https://regex101.com/r/e0EQP3/1

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use alternation and collect the undesireds, then capture the desired ones, maybe with some expression similar to

```
\\sigma|\\delta|pi|[\W0-9_]|([\w])
```

Those desired letters are in capturing group 1:

```
([\w])
```

```js
const regex = /\\sigma|\\delta|pi|[\W0-9_]|([\w])/gmi;
const str = `(1)/(2)+p_a*r*e*t*a*v+pi+\\delta+\\sigma

(1)/(2)+a_t*e*j*h*o+ \\Delta

(1)/(2)+p_w`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/INzGal/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/INzGal/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

### Method 2

Or we would just work it out a custom expression based on the patterns.

```
[w]|[ate](?=\*)|\b[pa](?=[^a-z])|\b[^(e|_)\d\W]\b
```

The problem is pertinent to word boundaries (`\b`) and underscores. Technically, underscore is part of the word construct `\w`.

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/XLBFDe/1/)

Comment: Take a look at this regex (https://regex101.com/r/LWQ9PG/1/). I need to capture just "p" and "a" in the first line, "a" and "t" in the second line and "p" and "w" in the third line. My regex already captures most of it. I need to delete the words as it is dynamic input.